# objects in an array alerted randomly

Tags: javascript

I have built this code using javascript that makes a few objects called monster. I then put those monsters in an array and finally am trying to call one of thous monsters to the console randomly. Unfortunately it displays in my console log as undefined. Any advice on how to get a random monster in the console log every time I refresh the page?

```
function Monster(type, level, mAttack, mAgility, mHP) {
    this.type = type;
    this.level = level; 
    this.mAttack = mAttack;
    this.mAgility = mAgility;
    this.mHP = mHP; 
}
Monster.prototype.logInfo = function() {
    console.log("I am a : ", this.type);
    console.log("I am level : ", this.level);
    console.log("I have the attack of : ", this.mAttack);
    console.log("I have the agility : ", this.mAgility);
    console.log("I have the health : ", this.mHP); 
}

var troll = new Monster("troll", 1, 10, 10, 10);
var skeleton = new Monster("skeleton", 1, 10, 10, 10);
var slime = new Monster("slime", 1, 10, 10);
var boar = new Monster("boat", 1, 10, 10);


var monsterList = new Array();
monsterList[0] = troll;
monsterList[1] = skeleton;
monsterList[3] = slime;
monsterList[4] = boar;


var summonRandomMonster = function (){
     monsterSummoner = monsterList[Math.floor(Math.random() * monsterList.length)];
}
console.log(monsterSummoner);
```

Comment: Your way of initialising an array is the worst possible. For one, you've skipped `monsterList[2]`. Use `monsterList = [troll, skeleton, slime, boar]` (or even inline the constructor calls into the array literal).

Comment: You need to put the code inside a function and invoke that with `document.onload`

Comment: @AkshatSinghal why would he? He's not doing any DOM lookup in his code

Comment: Thank you.. dont know why I got -2 their were alot of good answers and I learned alot thank you everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close... Change your last four lines as follows -

```
var monsterList = [troll,skeleton,slime,boar];

var summonRandomMonster = function (){
   monsterSummoner = monsterList[Math.floor(Math.random() * monsterList.length)];
   console.log(monsterSummoner);
}
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  summonRandomMonster();
}
```

Comment: This code works but it will randomly say undefined like 1 or 2 times out of 10 when I refresh the page? is this because I need to do something like length - 1 because im calling one more than the number of array items?

Comment: @user3117555 You've failed to put something at index 2.  Whenever your random number comes up as 2 it gets undefined because that slot in the array is never set.

Comment: I changed my array format to Monster { type="boat", level=1, mAttack=10, more...}
and it works great now thanks Jan Dvorak! and everyone!

Comment: Should I make the function a method of the Monster object?

Answer (score 3):

You create a function but never call it.  Therefor monsterSummoner is never set.

```
// THIS IS NEVER CALLED
var summonRandomMonster = function (){
     monsterSummoner = monsterList[Math.floor(Math.random() * monsterList.length)];
}

console.log(monsterSummoner);
```

Try this instead.  Notice that now that the function is called the value is set.

```
var monsterSummoner;
var summonRandomMonster = function (){
     monsterSummoner = monsterList[Math.floor(Math.random() * monsterList.length)];
}

summonRandomMonster();
console.log(monsterSummoner);
```

Comment: also, `monsterSummoner` should be declared; also see my comment about array initialisation, which is also a bug.

Answer (score 0):

There are atleast two problems in this code. The variable "monsterSummoner" is not defined, and the function "summonRandomMonster" is not called.